# How to correct a userform when error 13 is displayed in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm currently on a project that search in a product database all non-referenced product (blank fields). When I click on the button that opens a userform, error 13 is displayed, here is the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim r As Integer

t = 1
While Feuil3.Cells(t, 1) <> ""
t = t + 1
Wend
t = t - 1

For r = 2 To t
    If Feuil3.Cells(r, 3) = "" Then
    i = 1
    While Feuil2.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    i = i + 1
    Wend
    Feuil2.Cells(i, 1) = Feuil3.Cells(r, 2)
    End If
Next

i = 1
While Feuil2.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
i = i + 1
Wend

For j = 2 To i
    If Feuil2.Cells(j, 2) = "" Then
    list51.AddItem Feuil2.Cells(j, 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It appears that the error comes from this line:`If Feuil3.Cells(r, 3) = "" Then`

My skills in VBA are limited, do you have any idea on how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Check the sheet `Feuil3` exists

Comment: what is the value of `r` is it 2 or further on? and also the value of `t`

Comment: You will get that error if (for example) `Feuil3.Cells(r, 3)` contains an error.  It is telling you that whatever is in that cell can't be converted to a string for comparison with "".

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The value of r is 12955 and the value of t should be between 2 and r, but the error happen before the display.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Should do the same just a lot less iteratively

```
Dim Feuil2Rng As Range, Feuil3Rng As Range
Dim c

With Feuil3
    Set Feuil3Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
End With
For Each c In Feuil3Rng
    If c.Offset(0, 2) = vbNullString Then
        With Feuil2
            .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = c.Offset(0,1)
        End With
    End If
Next

With Feuil2
    Set Feuil2Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
End With

For Each c In Feuil2Rng
    If c.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then
        list51.AddItem c.Value2
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, but it's happen the same error... Do you think it's possible that it's due to the name of the sheet ? Or due to the number of lines (12955) ?